# Toggling iron-collapse using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm using multiple `<iron-collapse>`s with different IDs, and I have a `<paper-icon-button>` associated with each `<iron collapse>`.

I can use the `<iron-collapse>`s with their associated button when the screen is wider than `650px`, but in narrower widths, why does clicking the `<paper-icon-button>` not toggle the `<iron-collapse>`?

I even tried to change the class of a particular `<iron-collapse>`, but no luck. Toggling the display property didn't help.

Here's the `template`:

```
<paper-icon-button 
  class="pull-left" 
  id$="generalSectionToggle##[[yearEntries]]-[[monthEntries]]"
  icon="expand-less"
  on-click="toggleGeneralSection">
</paper-icon-button>
<iron-collapse id$="generalSection-[[yearEntries]]-[[monthEntries]]" opened="true">
   <div class="container-vertical">
     Some Content 
   </div>
</iron-collapse>
```

Here's the `on-click` handler (`toggleGeneralSection`):

```
var elementID = event.target.parentElement.id.split("##")[1]
var element = "generalSection-" + elementID
var domElement = document.getElementById(element);
if (window.innerWidth > 650) {
    domElement.toggle();  
} else {
    if (domElement.opened) {
        domElement.classList.toggle('iron-collapse-closed');
    } else {
        domElement.classList.toggle('iron-collapse-opened');
    }
}

if (domElement.opened) {
    event.target.icon = "expand-less";
} else {
    event.target.icon = "expand-more";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `iron-collapse` doesn't toggle when the window is less than `650px` because you're not calling `<iron-collapse>.toggle()` in that scenario. Instead, you're toggling an internal class. It seems the intention is to *always* toggle regardless of the screen width, so you should always call `<iron-collapse>.toggle()`.

Also, you should avoid using `document.getElementById()` in your click-handler to fetch the `<iron-collapse>` because it won't work in Shadow DOM. Instead, you could use [`this.$$(selector)`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/instance-methods#instance-methods). In your case, you're querying for an element ID, so you should prefix `element` with `#` (i.e., `"#generalSection-" + elementID`).

Your code should look more like this:

```js
var elementID = event.target.parentElement.id.split("##")[1]
var element = "#generalSection-" + elementID
var domElement = this.$$(element);
domElement.toggle();  

if (domElement.opened) {
    event.target.icon = "expand-less";
} else {
    event.target.icon = "expand-more";
}
```

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/LbjRQK?editors=1010) demo that toggles the `<iron-collapse>` with `<paper-icon-button>` and uses a [computed binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed) for the icon. And see this [codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/jrwkwG?editors=1010) for a variation that makes the header a clickable toggle.

Comment: Your code worked fine, but i want to know why it didn't worked in mobile mode, even i tried to use toggle instead of changing class.